Why is U6(2) a subgroup of the Conway group
The symmetry group of the Leech lattice is the double cover of Conway's sporadic group $Co_1$. The shortest nonzero vectors in this lattice are length $2$, and the stabilizer of such a vector is another sporadic group $Co_2$. Now, I know that the stabilizer of a $222$ triangle is isomorphic the projective special unitary group $U_6(2)$, but I can't think of a good reason why this is. I can imagine a few approaches to a proof:

There is an orbit of $891$ vectors, which we can map to the $891$ isotropic planes of $U_6(2)$. We can treat both $891$-orbits as vertices of graphs, then show that the graphs are isomorphic.
Since $U_6(2)$ has a BN pair, this gives a relatively easy-to-work-with presentation, and we could show that the Leech Lattice subgroup satisfies this presentation.
If we reduce the Leech lattice modulo $2$, the stabilizer of the triangle has a $20$-dimensional invariant subspace, which is isomorhpic to the exterior cube of $U_6(2)$.
If we know the character table of $U_6(2)$, we can see that there's a $22$-dimensional representation, which we could embed into the Leech lattice.

Of these approaches, the first or second seem like they would be the easiest. For the third approach, there are several orbits of vectors that need to be kept track of. And of course, the fourth approach requires calculating the character table, which is no easy task. That being said, I haven't tried sitting down to write a proof, so I don't know how easy or hard any of these approaches are, or if there's another way. My question is, what's a good way to prove that the stabilizer of a $222$ triangle in the Leech lattice is isomorphic to $U_6(2)$?

In the paper of Conway, he writes the stabilizer is "apparently" $PSU(6,2)$, and in a table there is a question mark next to $PSU(6,2)$. Suggesting that at least for Conway, at the time this was not immediately obvious. About identifying the various stabilizers, he states "Identifying these subgroups of $\cdot \infty$ with known groups is a haphazard process, and still incomplete. In some cases we use known characterisations of the groups concerned, and in others the identification is immediate when we choose simple coordinates for the vertices of S."
